# concat values group by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to get from this:

```
id   foo_name
1        A
2        A
3        A
4        A
5        B
6        B
7        B
8        A
9        B
10       A
```

to this:
1 row only

```
foo_names
A,B
```

I tried using `GROUP_CONCAT` but it give me this:

`A,A,A,A,A,A,A,`

`B,B,B,B`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select group_concat(distinct foo_name) as foo_names
from t;
```

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear enough but I have edited the question and it should only return in one row

Comment: @woninana . . . Did you run this?  It returns one row with just two values in the name.  That's what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

With `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(distinct foo_name order by foo_name) foo_names
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdo8TTCAQVKq2Levj6Auit/1).